# Are these three graphs isomorphic?

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

I believe that these three graphs are non-isomorphic, because the first graph contains a 6 cycle, which is not present in the other two graphs. The 2nd and 3rd graphs are not isomorphic because they have different numbers of 5 cycles.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to align the 2nd image in the center?

Comment: How many $5$-cycles have you counted in the second and third graphs?

Comment: $11$ in the second graph and $12$ in the third.

Comment: Keep counting in the second graph.

Comment: They both have $12$ $5$-cycles. :(

Comment: Are the 2nd and 3rd graphs isomorphic? @Blue

Comment: Right; same number of cycles, so you have to try something else. (This is why the Graph Isomorphism Problem is hard.) Try matching the $5$-cycles from one graph to those of the other. For instance, the inner $5$-cycle of the second graph would be a nice match for one of the "inner" $5$-cycles of the third; go from there. (It would be convenient if you could get the third graph's other "inner" $5$-cycle out of the way ... moving its vertices to the outside, for instance ...)

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd graph are both a ''2D version'' of the dodecahedron actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inner ring of the third graph consists of two disjoint 5-cycles.  If you "drag" one of them to the outside of the (current) outer ring, the isomorphism to the center graph will be clear.

You are correct that the first graph does not have a 5-cycle, so it cannot be isomorphic to the other two.